# Why is my script for a sprite applying to a tilemap? (Unity2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple top-down 2d movement demo as a personal project, and I've run into a very weird roadblock. I was using code from [this](https://stuartspixelgames.com/2018/06/24/simple-2d-top-down-movement-unity-c/) website to move the sprite, and it worked fine. I then drew in a simple structure using tilemap to test movement and collision of the sprite, but now when I use the arrow keys it moves the structure I painted in with the tilemap in an inverted control scheme (up arrow is down, left arrow is right, etc.). I have the script I wrote for the test sprite attached below. Can anyone help?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D body;

    float horizontal;
    float vertical;
    Vector2 move;

    public float runSpeed = 2.5f;

    void Start()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical"); 
        //move.x = horizontal;
        //move.y = vertical;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {  
        body.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * runSpeed, vertical * runSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your script shouldn't be able to interact with the tilemap at all if your script is located on the player character.

Comment: I don't think this is enough information / something weir is happening in your project ...

Comment: Does it still move if you disable this script? Any chance that it’s the camera that’s moving, not the TileMap? What object is assigned to the body variable?

Answer (score 0):

I know it was much worse but could you try? :)

```
body.velocity = new Vector2(-horizontal * runSpeed, -vertical * runSpeed);
```